# View todays calls in org mode's agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am using a tag `:Anrufe:` in my org files to mark calls I have to make. Some are regular calls (each Tuesday for example) and others have a specific date.

I have created an `org-agenda-custom-commands` entry in my config using `tags-todo` which gives me all calls which are not `DONE`, i.e. also those which are scheduled for next week. Is there a way to limit the display to the calls which are due today?

**EDIT**

I have tried already to use `org-agenda-span` but it seems to have no effect on `tags-todo`.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("h" "Was liegt heute an?"
         (org-agenda-span 'day)
         ((tags-todo "Anrufe"
                     ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Anrufe")
                      ))))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("h" "Was liegt heute an?"
         ((tags-todo "Anrufe"
                     ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Anrufe")
                      (org-agenda-span 'day)))))))
```

Comment: The first one is wrong I believe: there should be another set of parens around the org-agenda-span option (it's supposed to look like the settings in a `(let ...)`). The second one looks correct to me. However, I don't know off the top of my head why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but setting `org-agenda-span` in your agenda custom  command should work. E.g. here's a small modification of an [example in the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-options.html#Setting-options) that should do what you want for the "home" entries:

```
 (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
       '(("h" "Agenda and Home-related tasks"
          ((agenda)
           (tags-todo "home")
           (tags "garden"
                 ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-up)))))
          ((org-agenda-span 'day)
           (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-down))))
         ("o" "Agenda and Office-related tasks"
          ((agenda)
           (tags-todo "work")
           (tags "office")))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but see my edit. `org-agenda-span` seems to have no effect.